# Starling AS3 touch event press and hold

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have been search for a while now for a clear example of how to code a button that allows the user to press and hold. While this happens I would like to execute some code.

I have implemented the TouchEvent.Touch and the touchPhase.Began but it only fires once.

I cant find a clear explanation on how to implement this. Any help is appreciated.

```
btnPress.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, isPressed);

private function isPressed(event:TouchEvent){
    var touch:touch = event.getTouch(btnPress, TouchPhase.BEGAN);
    if(touch)
    {
        trace("pressed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starling `TouchEvent` and `TouchPhase` can be a little confusing at first. The `TouchPhase.BEGAN` only fires **once**, when the user starts touching the screen. If you want to execute some code **while the finger is on the button**, start executing on the `TouchPhase.BEGAN` phase and stop executing on the `TouchPhase.ENDED` phase (which fires also only once, when the user stops touching the screen).

For example, in your case you could do something like:

```
btnPress.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, isPressed);

private function isPressed(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    var touch:Touch = event.getTouch(btnPress);

    if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN)//on finger down
    {
        trace("pressed just now");

        //do your stuff
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onButtonHold);
    }

    if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED) //on finger up
    {
        trace("release");

        //stop doing stuff
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onButtonHold);
    }
}

private function onButtonHold(e:Event):void
{
    trace("doing stuff while button pressed!");
}
```

Hope this helps clarify things a little!

Comment: Thank you. TouchPhase's are a little confusing to start with.